# What should the tag for the new Windows 8 runtime be?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

At present, Microsoft seems to be calling the API for creating Metro style apps on Windows 8, “Windows Run Time”; it is also being called WinRt.

We already have two tags for this: [windows-runtime](/questions/tagged/windows-runtime) and [winrt](/questions/tagged/winrt). We only need one!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

My vote is for [winrt](/questions/tagged/winrt).  This is what [Google says](http://www.google.com/#q=winrt+microsoft), and what [everyone appears to be calling it](http://www.readwriteweb.com/hack/2011/09/build-2011-what-is-winrt-and-i.php).

Comment: Ok can you make windows-runtime a synonyms for winrt, so no one else tries to create it as a tag.

Comment: @Ian: [You're the only one calling it windows-runtime.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-runtime?sort=newest&pagesize=50) :P

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Irony.

Comment: @Robert, WinRt does not do any better at present, but give it a fews days for the questions to start flowing...

Comment: MSDN calls it "Windows Runtime" in most docs, so you can bet someone will use this. A synonym is a good idea.

Comment: And here I always thought WinRT was this: http://www.pds-site.com/Bsquare/WinRT/default.htm

Comment: @Gabe: Yeah, I saw that too.  We'll need a cage fight to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

I vote [windows-runtime](/questions/tagged/windows-runtime). IMHO, it is a lot more likely that the average user would know what that means than [winrt](/questions/tagged/winrt).

Comment: We don't care about the "average user" as SO is a programmer's site.

Comment: The average user of SO.

Comment: windows-runtime is far too ambiguous. There are many such runtimes (i.e. any runtime that executes in a Windows environment).  It should probably be either windows-8-runtime or winrt

Comment: @Robert windows-8-runtime I understand, but I fail to see how winrt is *less* ambiguous than windows-runtime.

Comment: @John `winrt` may be unclear to those unfamiliar with it, but it's not ambiguous because other Windows runtimes aren't referred to as "winrt".

Comment: winrt is a "proper" name, like "John."

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Well, WinRt, but tags don't support capitalization...

Comment: Most people who worked with it so far know it as WinRT, and it's also what's used in the source code and thereabouts - e.g. header files for it in Developer Preview are in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\winrt\", and the most fundamental one is called "winrt.h". Users on MSDN forums also seem to be mostly using "WinRT". I'd suggest sticking to that, especially as it is a fairly unique label that is also convenient for search engines and such.