# Is tag sponsorship contributing to confusion between "metro" and "metro-ui"?

Tags: discussion, tags, sponsored-tags

We've discussed the Windows 8 / Metro situation before.

- [What should the tag for the new Windows 8 runtime be?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106163/what-should-the-tag-for-the-new-windows-8-runtime-be)
- [Consensus on taxonomy for Windows Phone, Windows 8, and things named Metro?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122153/consensus-on-taxonomy-for-windows-phone-windows-8-and-things-named-metro)
- [Windows 8 and related tags need a little love](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106716/windows-8-and-related-tags-need-a-little-love)
- [Should the "metro" tag refer to a Java framework or Windows 8 technology?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120158/should-the-metro-tag-refer-to-a-Java-framework-or-windows-8-technology)

But people are still tagging stuff [metro](/questions/tagged/metro) when it should be [metro-ui](/questions/tagged/metro-ui). Today I was wondering - do they even read anything we show them? I brought up the tagged questions to easily find the other wrong ones and look what I saw:

[image: metro tag]

I think this sponsorship is "outweighing" the actual text of the tag wiki. Maybe the excerpt should be first. Maybe Soluto shouldn't be allowed to sponsor [metro](/questions/tagged/metro), only [metro-ui](/questions/tagged/metro-ui).

**Update:** It's been two weeks and the [metro](/questions/tagged/metro) folks are still at it. In fact I am now seeing questions tagged with both [metro](/questions/tagged/metro) and [metro-ui](/questions/tagged/metro-ui) showing that they know about the "right" tag but they think the other one is also right. I don't understand why people are allowed to sponsor "wrong" tags like this. I would really like an answer about that part of it.

Comment: Thoughts?  What a mess.

Comment: A mess is correct. Purge the tag!!

Comment: the metro tag in't hurting anyone and has 150 real questions. It's just that every day I have to redirect 2 or 3 (sometime more, and maybe I'm not the only one doing it) to where they belong, metro-ui. The sponsorship sure isn't helping.

Comment: You're not going to fix this problem, most Windows devs seem to call it "Metro" rather than "Metro UI". The SO-savvy may read the tag excerpt, but the rest are going to use Metro and forget about it. This will always be a losing battle.

Comment: Whatever happened to that suggestion of renaming it [java-metro-framework]?

Comment: I agred with @six that this might require long term maintainance. That said, I think SE Inc. should at least let the sponsor know that they're sponsoring the wrong tag!

Answer (score 5):

[metro](/questions/tagged/metro) is ambiguous and has to go, or you'll keep getting questions accidentally tagged to it.

I would suggest to use [metro-web](/questions/tagged/metro-web) or [metro-web-java](/questions/tagged/metro-web-java) or [metro-java](/questions/tagged/metro-java) instead:

- [metro-web](/questions/tagged/metro-web) makes the user more likely to read what it is, but accidental tags could still happen.
- [metro-web-java](/questions/tagged/metro-web-java) is as verbose as it can gets, no way that you can misunderstand that.
- [metro-java](/questions/tagged/metro-java) could work as well, since the `web` notion might not be necessary.

Don't add `framework` because it adds no value to the tag name.

---

So, here's the approach I would suggest:

1. Contact the sponsor that he is sponsoring the wrong tag.
2. Sort out [metro](/questions/tagged/metro) to only contain Java Metro-related questions, [metro-ui](/questions/tagged/metro-ui) for the design language.
3. Move all questions from [metro](/questions/tagged/metro) to [metro-web-java](/questions/tagged/metro-web-java) or [metro-java](/questions/tagged/metro-java).
4. Call Trogdor using the awesome sign and ask him to burninate [metro](/questions/tagged/metro) (and blacklist it).
5. *???*
6. Profit! Everybody happy...

Here is an image explaining it all with tags, SE team, sponsor(s), freehand circles, unicorns and Trogdor:

[image]

*Any resemblance with real-life persons, drakes or unicorns is purely coincidentally...*

Comment: How could anyone argue with this answer? I'll just point out that I (and possibly others) are doing step 2 by hand at the moment. I check the metro tag every day and fix what I find. I long for someone to do step 1. Steps 3-5 are optional, though I do look forward to step 6 assuming I am the one who gets to profit.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's pretty clear the answer to the title question is `YES`. The sponsor info disappeared from both [metro](/questions/tagged/metro) and [metro-ui](/questions/tagged/metro-ui) two days ago. I have not needed to edit a single tag since then. **Not one!**

Unless someone else has taken up the torch and has been doing the edits, I think that removing the sponsorship did the trick. I'm actually a little surprised to see such a clear line. If someone knows exactly when it was removed and wants to compare to my edit history, I'd be interested in the time spans involved.

(Damn! After two clear days including an entire Monday, I spotted a mis-tag and fixed it.)