# Can the tag-verifying routine react to mismatching (misinterpreting) tags?

Tags: feature-request, tags

I'm continuing to deal with the Windows 8 tags pretty regularly. (Some links in [Is tag sponsorship contributing to confusion between "metro" and "metro-ui"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125890/is-tag-sponsorship-contributing-to-confusion-between-metro-and-metro-ui/127921#127921)) I have an idea for a way to prevent some of the trouble.

Using a similar mechanism to tag-synonyms, users with the appropriate powers could declare certain tags to be "mismatches" to this one. So for [windows-8](/questions/tagged/windows-8), [metro](/questions/tagged/metro) would be a mismatch and the text shown to the user could be:

> Please use [metro-ui](/questions/tagged/metro-ui) for Windows 8 Metro Application questions.

For [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), [c](/questions/tagged/c) could be a mismatch with the text:

> C and C++ are different languages; most questions need only one of these tags.

That one would probably also be added in the other order. Same for [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) and [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net) - why would anyone tag a question with both? (But they do.)

Perhaps you wouldn't refuse to post a question with mismatched tags, or maybe you would refuse for lower-rep users and at some point allow it. But just providing some context-sensitive help, where the context is the other tags you've used, would help avoid mistaggings.

Comment: "why would anyone tag a question with both?" - for [tag:c#] and [tag:vb.net], it's generally when the question's about translating one to the other.

Comment: @AakashM: That's what the [tag:c#-to-vb.net] and [tag:vb.net-to-c#] tags are for.

Comment: @TheEstablishment cool, thanks :)