# Sorry, again, Windows 8 Metro, etc

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

I know I know. We've done this before.

- [Consensus on taxonomy for Windows Phone, Windows 8, and things named Metro?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122153/consensus-on-taxonomy-for-windows-phone-windows-8-and-things-named-metro)
- [Should the "metro" tag refer to a Java framework or Windows 8 technology?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120158/should-the-metro-tag-refer-to-a-java-framework-or-windows-8-technology)
- [What should the tag for the new Windows 8 runtime be?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106163/what-should-the-tag-for-the-new-windows-8-runtime-be)
- [Windows 8 and related tags need a little love](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106716/windows-8-and-related-tags-need-a-little-love)
- [Metro tags still a giant mess](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137135/metro-tags-still-a-giant-mess)
- [Sorting out tagging for WinRT (Windows Runtime) and Windows RT (Windows on ARM)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152477/sorting-out-tagging-for-winrt-windows-runtime-and-windows-rt-windows-on-arm)

But someone has created [windows-store-apps](/questions/tagged/windows-store-apps) (434 questions and a tag wiki) when there is still [microsoft-metro](/questions/tagged/microsoft-metro) with 2544 questions. I know that when Metro was a thing, it was a thing that spanned UIs - phone, Windows 8, even websites and slide decks (heaven help me, especially slide decks) could be metro-y. But in terms of Stack Overflow questions it was mostly what we now call [Windows Store](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Store) apps.

So, synonyms? Tag cleanup? Clear direction in the wiki to help people choose? It once again needs a little love.

Update: it seems we also have [windows-runtime](/questions/tagged/windows-runtime) as well.

Comment: When `windows-store-apps` was first created, it was let through because the terminology and jargon used seemed like it was a totally separate thing than the Metro clusterf*.  Is this not the case?

Comment: The tag wiki for Windows Store apps is correct. They refer to what were called Metro style apps on Windows 8. That makes them a large part of the clusterwhoops and I would guess every question tagged windows-store-app could instead be tagged windows-8 and microsoft-metro.

Comment: Oh my aching head.  BRB, driving to Redmond to scream at the naming people [*again*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/152477/135887).

Comment: Mmmm, hence my new tag. This one just won't go away.

Comment: There was a slight problem in Germany, where someone apparently registered the trademark about 45 years ago. Just a couple of hundred stores, or something. Who would notice? http://www.metro24.de/pages/DE/HomePage

Comment: @Bo I know why they dropped Metro, but not why they didn't replace it with anything, then tried several (Microsoft Design Language, Microsoft Style, etc) before kinda sorta settling on Windows Store, which is not a good name. And as Charles points out, WinRT vs Windows RT is verging on insane. But all we need to do here is sort out how the heck to tag the questions. We can't solve the bigger problem.